# Formatting, integers, and dicts in POST request

Tags: ajax, post, scrapy

The script on the server sends back `data.location` and redirects the browser to `data.location`, which I want to capture in my script. This code returns `{"location": null}`:

```
def load_page(self, response):
    """
    Get server response for the data sent.

    FormRequest from Chrome console:

    location:https://www.example.com/menu/
    top_level:false                                   <--- boolean
    section:4                                         <--- integer
    departmets:[{"desc":"dep-select", "value":"119"}] <--- string (?)

    """
    url = urlparse.urljoin(self.var.root[:-1], 'navigation/load_department/')
    formdata={'location':'https://www.example.com/menu/',
              'section': '4', 
              'departments':'[{"desc":"dep-select", "value":"119"}]',
              'top_level': 'False'}

    return scrapy.FormRequest(url=url,
                   method='POST', 
                   formdata=formdata, 
                   callback=self.next_page)
```

What I expect is `{"location": 'some URL'}`.

- I suspect it's because the 4 above is integer which I managed to send only as a string.
- If I send it as an integer, scrapy complains that it expects only str or unicode.
- If I send the request as `formdata=json.dumps(...)`, there is another error about unpacking the values.
- Scrapy does not accept dict in `departments=`.
- Request with `Request(body=json(...))` returns only `{}`.

How can I pass this integer to `formdata`, and/or is this a properly formatted POST request?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like scrapy only accepts strings (and lists) as the body for POST requests, which is ok, because when the server receives that information, it won't handled the type, it will always be [formatted](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1)

Comment: This actually worked as intended, the only thing is I expected another request. So yes, strings only.